# Get file name is open in auto desk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

In the question :
[How to retrieve filename from Forge Viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64593888/how-to-retrieve-filename-from-forge-viewer)

I used this :

NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().loadOptions.bubbleNode.getRootNode().children[0].name()

but this name only return first file rvt i open . I open 2 file , only return first file name open So how to return the name of the 2nd file ?

Answer (score 0):

the loaded models are managed by NOP_VIEWER.getAllModels(). So you can find specific model such as

```
  model = NOP_VIEWER.getAllModels()[1]  //the second model
```

and call

```
   model.getData().loadOptions.bubbleNode.getRootNode().children[0].name()
```

There is also another model collection which tells the visible models only.

```
   NOP_VIEWER.getVisibleModels()
```

Comment: I use only this code :
`model = NOP_VIEWER.getAllModels()[1]  //the second model`

Return array has 1 data , this is the first file rvt i open, can't show file rvt 2 nd i open